# Deleted session variables after session_regenerate_id()

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to get my head around PHP Sessions.

I'm using ShortPHP as a router, but the ShortPHP code doesn't touch sessions.

The template has `session_start()` as the first line:-

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 's.php';
var_dump($_SESSION);
$sid = session_id();
echo $sid;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
```

This template is executed first for every page (I've added the first few lines (var_dump etc) in order to debug), followed by the specific page code.  In this instance, I'm using the following code:-

```
<?php
if (!defined('S')) die ("You've got no S"); // part of ShortPHP - irrelevant

if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] != "1") {
        echo "<p>Session is NOT set</p>";
        //header() redirect to login here...
        //exit();
}

$sri = session_regenerate_id();
var_dump($sri);

 ?>
```

If I  comment out `session_regenerate_id()` then the session variable (`login`) is still available after reloading the page, but with `session_regenerate_id()` enabled, the session variable is deleted when I reload the page.  Note that `session_regenerate_id()` returns `true` every time.

I've even gone as far as to read the session stored on the server, and the file for the original session has the session variable data within it, while, after a page reload, the new session file has no variables (file size is zero).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any output to the browser before you reset the ID and what does `session_regenerate_id()` return?

Comment: Edited the question with answers to your questions: Yes and True

Comment: Strange. Does it make a difference if you use `session_regenerate_id()` before the headers are sent (output is sent to the browser)?

Comment: @jeroen: I've placed `session_regenerate_id()` on the third line of the template (after the `session_start()`) and it didn't help.  It still shows the session variable after login put it's empty when I refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry, this is a mystery to me, it should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause was `session.cookie_secure` being set in `php.ini` when https wasn't used.  Once I removed that setting, the session lasted between page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's a good idea to pass `true` as a parmeter to `session_regenerate_id();` as that will remove the old session data.

Comment: The whole idea is to avoid removing old session data - I was hoping it would be passed to the new session id.

Comment: It should be, passing true deletes the old session that still exists which cause pose a security concern. The previous data should be available with the new session ID.

Comment: It is usually not good idea to remove old session data before analyzing it and tracking attacks. So it is better not to pass `true` to session_regenerate_id() unless you don`t bother about attackers.